# Unable to create fulltext search with eventually_consistent setting

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am currently getting the error

```
Missing kernel to cypher mapping for limitation: EVENTUALLY_CONSISTENT
```

When I try to create on a node/label that has a fulltext index setup.

Fulltext search index setup code:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex(
        "titleAndKeywords",
        [
            ...label_names
        ],
        [
            ...properties
        ],
        {
            eventually_consistent : "true"
        });
```

Removing the `eventually_consistent` in the creation fixes this

On version 4.0.4

Comment: Did you figure out the issue? I am facing something similar.